# Hue - restrict users from creating queries

Tags: hue

Is it possible to restrict users from creating queries in hue hive editor? They should only be able to run saved queries.

Comment: The usual solution is to run "canned reports" in batch and send the results by e-mail. There's no point in using an interactive tool and trying to suppress the interactions...

Comment: This is currently not possible indeed